# Visualforce component licence in managed package

Tags: appexchange, licenses, userlicense

I have a visualforce component added in my managed package. Using a custom page I am allowing users to create vf pages automatically that use my component from the managed package. The created page is used in the layout of different objects as inline vf page. But I noticed that the licence restrictions are not working on vf component. Even if the user doesn't have a licence to use my app, the inline vf page renders without any 'Licence required' error.

However users are not able to view custom objects or other pages which are the part of my package if they don't have licence. These pages show the 'Licence required' error as expected.